# Sklearn - Cannot use encoded data in Random forest classifier

Tags: python, encoding, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit-learn. I'm trying use preprocessing. OneHotEncoder to encode my training and test data. After encoding I tried to train Random forest classifier using that data. But I get the following error when fitting.
(Here the error trace)

```
    99         model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    100         preds = model.predict_proba(X_cv)[:, 1]
    101 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    288 
    289         # Precompute some data
--> 290         X, y = check_arrays(X, y, sparse_format="dense")
    291         if (getattr(X, "dtype", None) != DTYPE or
    292                 X.ndim != 2 or

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_arrays(*arrays, **options)
    200                     array = array.tocsc()
    201                 elif sparse_format == 'dense':
--> 202                     raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
    203                                     'data is required. Use X.toarray() to '
    204                                     'convert to a dense numpy array.')

TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

I tried to convert the sparse matrix into dense using X.toarray() and X.todense()
But when I do that, I get the following error trace.

```
 99         model.fit(X_train.toarray(), y_train)
    100         preds = model.predict_proba(X_cv)[:, 1]
    101 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.pyc in toarray(self)
    548 
    549     def toarray(self):
--> 550         return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray()
    551 
    552     ##############################################################

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.pyc in toarray(self)
    236 
    237     def toarray(self):
--> 238         B = np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
    239         M,N = self.shape
    240         coo_todense(M, N, self.nnz, self.row, self.col, self.data, B.ravel())

ValueError: array is too big.
```

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

sklearn random forests do not work on sparse input and your dataset shape is to large and too sparse for a dense version to fit in memory.

You probably have some categorical features with a much to large cardinality (for instance a free text field or unique entry ids). Try to drop those features and start over.

Comment: It's time to fix the random forests :)

Comment: Agreed, albeit in this case it's very likely that naively applying onehotencoder on very high cardinality features would not work even if we had sparse input support in RFs. Noisy features will never help.

Comment: You mean the OP should do feature selection first?

Comment: I mean OP should not use OneHotEncoder on features that have unique values such as a sample identifier or a free text field.