# How do I do classification using TfidfVectorizer plus metadata in practice?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using trying to classify some documents into two classes, in which I use TfidfVectorizer as an feature extraction technique.

Input data consists of rows of data containing about a dozen fields of float data, label and the text blob of the body of the document. In order of use the body, I applied the TfidfVectorizer and got a sparse matrix (which I can examine by converting to array via toarray() ). This matrix is usually very large, thousands by thousands dimensions - let's call this F which has size 1000 x 15000.

To use a classifier in Scikit, I give it an input matrix X which is (number of rows * number of features). If I do not use the body, I have maybe an X of size 1000 x 15.

Here is the problem, suppose I append horizontally stack this F to X, so X will become 1000 x 15015, which introduces a few problems:
1) The first 15 features will be playing a very little role now;
2) Out-of-memory;

Scikit has provided an example where using solely the TfidfVectorizer input, but shed no light on how to use it *along side* the metadata.

My question is: **How do you use the TfidfVectorizer output along with the metadata to fit into a classifier for training?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

1. Extract bag of words (tf-idf) features, call these `X_tfidf`.
2. Extract metadata features, call these `X_metadata`.
3. Stack them together:

   ```
   X = scipy.sparse.hstack([X_tfidf, X_metadata])
   ```
4. If it doesn't work as expected, try re-normalizing:

   ```
   from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
   X = normalize(X, copy=False)
   ```

If you use a linear estimator such as `LinearSVC`, `LogisticRegression` or `SGDClassifier`, you shouldn't worry about the role that features play in the classification; this is the estimator's work. Linear estimators assign a weight to each individual feature that tells how informative the feature is, i.e. they figure this out for you.

(Non-parametric, distance/similarity-based models such as kernel SVMs or k-NN may have a harder time on such datasets.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. You're right that I should leave it to the estimator's to figure out. I will try it out, though (probably specific to implementation), the ensembles (RandomForest, GDT) etc doesn't seem to work on sparse matrix with error message : "A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.", which is a dead-end, Ogriesel already confirmed [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184079/sklearn-cannot-use-encoded-data-in-random-forest-classifier[/link] .

Comment: @log0: that's a known defect. Try a linear model, or do some dimensionality reduction.

Comment: So it's a bug in Scikit Learn to be fixed? I have always thought about trying to pick up something to contribute maybe, albeit small ... =]

Comment: @log0: we call it a missing feature, but it's definitely something worth implementing and any assistance is welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic way of merging tf-idf descriptors with other type of data, everything depends on your particular model and data:

- Some models are designed to deal with data that can be of arbitrary scales, and so - they use the strongest predictors, no matter if they are just 1% of the whole feature vector. Some decision trees information criterions can be a good example of such methods
- Some models let you directly "weight" the features to make them more important then others, so you can include some expert knowledge in order to weight the meta data with the large non-meta part, by for example N_not_meta/N_meta scale, where N_x is the number of x-type features dimensions. SVMs let you do such thing, as they are scale dependant linear models, so simple feature rescaling can have such effect. Also in probabilistic models like Naive Bayes you can force some predictors to be "strong" by multiplying their respective "probability estimates" by some predefined factor.
- The more advanced approach would be to create an ensamble of classifiers - one for meta data, and one for the tfidf and some meta-classifier (as the voting scheme for 2 models is rather useless) trained on their outputs
- You can also simply reduce dimensionality of the second part by performing some dimensionality reduction method (eg. PCA)

The choice of particular method is strongly problem specific, but as you can see - there are many possibilities and no possibility of selecting simply "the best one".

For out-of-memory problems you should consider **sparse** representation which is avaliable in scikit-learn. It is a good choice for NLP data, as documents tend to have very sparse feature vectors.

Comment: Thanks Lejlot for your reply. Indeed, I didn't think of using two models - one of metadata and one for the actual data. I will try to refrain from doing the expert weighting, but maybe letting the estimator figure it out (ensemble of ensembles, etc). Also, due to using Scikit-learn, if I decide to use RandomForest, it won't work on sparse inputs, which is sad. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184079/sklearn-cannot-use-encoded-data-in-random-forest-classifier]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to perform a semantic projection of `X_tfidf` using a topic model such as [sklearn.decomposition.NMF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html).

This allows inputting sparse matrices, and outputs a set of features that is **non-sparse** and **small-dimensional**. Therefore, *this overcomes the two issues mentioned in the answers above (sparse input and limited memory)*.

Example projecting the `X_tfidf` vectors to 20-D feature vectors:

```
nmf = NMF(n_components=20)
nmf.fit(data)
X_transformed = nmf.transform(X_tf_idf)
```

Here "data" is whatever set of features given to fit the factorization model (ideally, a held-out set of features).

And then you could safely merge it with other features

```
X = scipy.sparse.hstack([X_transfored, X_metadata])
```

Other projections are possible, such as PCA, but topic models through matrix factorizations such as NMF or [SVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) are common in text classification.