# Gradient Boosting Classifier sparse matrix issue using pandas and scikit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, kaggle

I have been using the following code to do multiclass classification which uses GradientBoostingClassifier from scikit-learn. I am facing a known issue with sparse matrix Conversion to dense matrix.

I have applied the following solution [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184079/sklearn-cannot-use-encoded-data-in-random-forest-classifier) but it doesnt work for my case. Although the solution I used is meant for RandomForestClassifier but AFAIK it should work for GradientBoostingClassifier!

Also to add this code works perfectly if I replace GradientBoostingClassifier with RandomForestClassifier.

The data in this case is numeric 93 features with 8 target classes. The data can be fetched from [Kaggle](http://kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge)

```
# load data
train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')
sample = pd.read_csv('submissions/sampleSubmission.csv')
labels = train.target.values
ids = train.id.values
train = train.drop('id', axis=1)
train = train.drop('target', axis=1)
train_orig = train
test = test.drop('id', axis=1)

# transform counts to TFIDF features
tfidf = feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer()
train = tfidf.fit_transform(train)
test = tfidf.transform(test).toarray() # Update line

# encode labels 
lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
labels = lbl_enc.fit_transform(labels)

# train a random forest classifier
print('starting training ... ')
clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier( n_estimators=config.estimators)
clf.fit(train, labels)

# predict on test set
print('starting prediction ... ')
preds = clf.predict_proba(test) # Error on this line even when test is dense
train_pred = clf.predict(tfidf.transform(train_orig))
```

Traceback:

```
python boosted_trees.py 
starting training ... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boosted_trees.py", line 57, in <module>
    clf.fit(train, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py", line 941, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=DTYPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 439, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",     line 331, in check_array
    copy, force_all_finite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",     line 239, in _ensure_sparse_format
    raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use         X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.ere
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, and without giving a traceback it is near impossible to help.

Comment: Sorry, I have added traceback!

Comment: You didn't make your training data dense.

Comment: added the data structure and code used for loading!

Comment: I just told you the error...

Comment: please see the link i posted it says toarray() will convert data to dense, but see line test = tfidf.transform(test).toarray(). toarray() should have made the test variable dense.

Comment: You need to make `train` dense, you already did with `test`.

Comment: It dosent makes sense but I already tried, it still has the same error on the same line of preds = clf.predict_proba(test)

Comment: It might be because you removed `toarray` from `test` now. Both of them need to be dense. Try with `toarray()` and the end of both `train` and `test`.

Comment: Yes! adding toarray() to train, test, train_orig and labels fixed this! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @imaluengo.

Just in case anyone needs. The issue is in these lines.

```
train = tfidf.fit_transform(train)
test = tfidf.transform(test).toarray() # Update line
```

Both lines should have a toarray() to fix this.

```
train = tfidf.fit_transform(train).toarray()
test = tfidf.transform(test).toarray() # Update line
```